# Delete many2many column in table and the table itself - odoo 13

Tags: many-to-many, migrate, odoo-13

While running a pre-migration script to delete a (wizard) transient model, ended up with below mentioned issue.

```
from openupgradelib import openupgrade


@openupgrade.migrate()
def migrate(env, version):    
    openupgrade.delete_records_safely_by_xml_id(
        env,
        ["moduel_name.view_id)"],
        delete_childs=True,
    )

    try:
        env.cr.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name CASCADE")
        env.cr.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dependent_table_names CASCADE")

    except Exception as e:
        raise ("Exception--------------", e)
```

Error:

```
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: update or delete on table "ir_model" violates foreign key constraint "ir_model_relation_model_fkey" on table "ir_model_relation"
```

Similar issue: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/54178

According to the above issue, having Many2many in transient model might cause this issue. It is true in my case as well. I have many2many fields. No solution there.

I kind of tried deleting the problematic fields(Many2many) before deleting columns. But it is known that many2many fields can't be located in db. kind of stuck.

```
openupgrade.drop_columns(
    env.cr,
    [
        ("table_name", "any_other_column_name"), # ---> This works
        ("table_name", "many2many_column_name"), # ---> This doesn't
    ],
)
```

is there anyway to get rid of many2many fields from the model ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this :

Let's say your Transient is `my_transient_model` and the Many2many field is e.g. `sale_line_ids = fields.Many2many('sale.order_line')`

First thing to know : Did you specify the relation table ? like

`sale_line_ids = fields.Many2many('sale.order_line', 'my_relation_table_name')` ?

If so, `'my_relation_table_name'` is the name you want to delete from ir_model_relation.

If not, the relation table name is my_transient_model_sale_order_line_rel (so `model` then `_` then `the model we point to with _ instead of .` then `_rel`.

Second set: delete the data from ir_model_relation:

`DELETE FROM ir_model_relation WHERE name='my_transient_model_sale_order_line_rel';`

Then you should be able to delete the Many2many table :

`DROP TABLE my_transient_model_sale_order_line_rel;`

(for sure, change `my_transient_model_sale_order_line_rel` if you specified the relation table like `my_relation_table_name` in the example)

Hope it helped, keep me updated :)